# How can i convert a input text field with a specific function into a textarea which performs the same function?

Tags: javascript, php, function, input, textarea

i wonder if there is a way to convert an input type text field into a regular textarea with exactly the same function.

*Got actually this here:*

```
<input id="msg" class="msg-user'.$uid.'" name="msg" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { postmsg('.$uid.', 1) }">
```

*What i tried was:*

```
    <textarea id="msg" class="msg-user'.$uid.'" name="msg" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { postmsg('.$uid.', 1) }"></textarea>
```

but it returned just an ***undefined*** instead of my text.
Is it even possible to convert it to a textarea as it is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably this in is a PHP echo (or var)? Otherwise `class="msg-user'.$uid.'"` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes you have to echo $uid

Comment: The issue might be with the `postmsg` but we don't see what does that do.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<textarea id="msg" class="msg-user<?php echo $uid;?>" name="msg" 
  onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { postmsg('<?php echo $uid;?>', 1) }"></textarea>
```

Just replace `postmsg('<?php echo $uid;?>', 1)`  with `postmsg('.$uid.', 1)`  because `'.$uid.'` is a string you need to be `**echo**` this `$uid`.

Comment: Did you try this ?

Comment: Hi i was abroad so sorry for my late reply, but my first attempt failed, seems like i'm going to have a few days of tiral and error fun but i really want to make it work with your code.